# build angular 4 project for production

Tags: angular, build

I'am working on angular 4 project.
when I  run  "ng build -prod -aot=false" to  build project for production, I have error message as you can see below :

Time: 44075ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.d8674538798840c67825.bundle.js (polyfills) 252 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.2d2d57386cb503360e3d.bundle.js (main) 72 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} scripts.d0a13d2099c21c77943a.bundle.js (scripts) 410 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} styles.aef7beffbbfb61f4f445.bundle.css (styles) 175 bytes {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} vendor.e29287b60dbca26b1047.bundle.js (vendor) 3.43 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {5} inline.6266454082b265a77bf0.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

"ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 66:27 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Ashirama_workspace/angularproject/src/app/app.module.ts"

here is  my app.modu.ts file:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
    import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-
    browser/animations';
    import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { AuthGuard } from './shared/';
    import {Guards}from './guards/guards';
    import {AuthenticationService} from 
    "./services/authentification.service";
    import {UserService} from "./services/user.service";
    import {HttpService} from "./services/http.service";
    import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
    import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig, AUTH_PROVIDERS, provideAuth } from 
     'angular2-jwt';
    import {ToastModule} from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';
    import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
    import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/alert';
    import { Ng2BootstrapModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

    // AoT requires an exported function for factories
    export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
    // for development
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/', '.json');
     }
     @NgModule({
       declarations: [
       AppComponent

     ],
     imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     BrowserAnimationsModule,
     FormsModule,
     ReactiveFormsModule,
     HttpModule,
     HttpClientModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     ToastModule.forRoot(),
     ToastrModule.forRoot(),
     AlertModule.forRoot(),
     Ng2BootstrapModule,
     TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [Http]
          }
        })
      ],
     providers: [
     AuthGuard,
     AuthenticationService,
     UserService,
     HttpService,
     Guards,
     AuthHttp,
     provideAuth({
        headerName: 'Authorization',
        headerPrefix: 'Bearer',
        tokenName: 'id_token',
        tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('id_token')),
        globalHeaders: [{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }],
        noJwtError: true
    })


    ],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
      })
      export class AppModule {
        }
```

please let me know what I'am doing wrong thank you

Comment: Can you post your `app.module.ts` or where ever you have your lambda function ( `() => function`) defined?

Comment: it's done I update my post  with app.modulte.ts contains file as your ask.

Comment: let me mentioned that most of function I use is  service  and look like that  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your lambda functions `() => something` to an export function like

```
export function doSomething() {
  ....
}
```

See [this Github post](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4956) for a more detailed description.

**EDIT:**

In your case, you have to replace the `provideAuth` and `AuthHttp` with the factory method:

```
export function getAuthHttp(http) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    headerName: 'Authorization',
    headerPrefix: 'Bearer',
    tokenName: 'id_token',
    tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('id_token')),
    globalHeaders: [{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }],
    noJwtError: true
  }), http);
}
```

and then

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: getAuthHttp,
      deps: [Http]
    },
```

Comment: I have just try your suggest but error still appear

Comment: Can you update your post with the code which throws the error?

Comment: I changed app.module.ts  file as your suggested and a new error occure: ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'provideAuth', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/angularproject/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/angularproject/dropnet_mise_en_prod/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\Ashirama_workspace\dropnet_mise_en_prod\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

Comment: ok, so you should use the facotry pattern instead of `provideAuth` of angular2-jwt like they are suggesting it at https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#advanced-configuration

Comment: after tryed what your suggested me , error message changed to become ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\projectangular\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

Comment: Well, then there seems to be another problem somewhere, but that is not part of this question then. Your 'Error encountered resolving symbol values statically' is solved and you should post a new question then.

Comment: just for tell you that  I succed to build project with AOT parameter ng build --prod --aot=false  thank's for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tree shaking is not happening properly. Its resolved in angular cli 1.4.x but if your are using previous version of angular cli you can add reflect metadata and try build again.

`npm install -save reflect-metadata`